# Add Categories page Database Error Occurred

Tags: php, database

Hello when i try to add a categories page i got this message:

> Error Number: 1364 Field 'total' doesn't have a default value INSERT
>   INTO `page_categories` (`name`, `description`) VALUES ('News', 'news')
>   Filename: /storage/ssd5/755/6853755/public_html/models/admin_model.php
>   Line Number: 106

This is my admin_model.php line 106:

```
103         public function add_page_category($name, $desc) 
104         {
105         $this->db->insert("page_categories", array("name" => $name,
106             "description" => $desc));
107         }
```

Comment: Well, isn't the error message crystal clear? You try to add a row into a database table, you do NOT specify a value for field `total` and there is no default value defined for that field.

Comment: you have a field `total` in DB where you do not have set a default value.